# Do $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ span the same column space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Do $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ span the same column space? I have found a question that asks whether matrix B is a multiple of matrix A if both of them have the same 4 fundamental subspaces. The answer was that 2 invertible matrices can have the same  4 fundamental matrices and not be multiple of each others. An example provided: $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. However, as I asked in the beginning how can it be possible that $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ span the same column space?

Comment: $$\text{span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right\}=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}r \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \mid r \in \Bbb R\right\}$$ $$\text{span}\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right\}=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ r \end{bmatrix} \mid r \in \Bbb R\right\}$$ clearly neither span the same space. But since you added the word column I think your problem is about some related matrix not the vectors

Comment: @N8tron I took columns of the matrices from my question. Or you mean something else by saying related matrix? I just didn't really understand. The columns of the matrices don't span the same column space, am I correct?

Comment: Your question begins with stuff about the 4 fundamental subspaces of a matrix, one of which is the column space. In the example, the column space of each matrix is all of $\mathbb R^2$, because $\{\binom10,\binom02\}$ spans $\mathbb R^2$ and so does $\{\binom20,\binom01\}$. But then you somehow jump from that to the column spaces spanned by $\binom10$ and by $\binom01$. I don't understand how you made that jump.

Comment: @andreas-blass I took the first column of the first matrix and the second column of the second matrix and compared them. The result of comparison was that they are not the same and thus they don't span the same column space. May be I failed in comparing them? Do I need to compare only the spaces that they span, which is R^2 in both cases, or the elements and their positions too, as I did?

Comment: Why did you expect that the first column of one matrix and the second column of the other should span the same subspace? If two matrices have the same column space, that's information only about what's spanned by all the columns together of the one matrix and all the columns together of the other matrix. It implies nothing about what's spanned by a single column of one matrix and a single column of the other matrix.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So, several matrices (m by n) have the same 4 fundamental spaces if they all have the same rank?

Comment: If they have the same fundamental spaces then they have the same rank, but the converse is false in general. In fact, it seems that the converse holds only in the case of invertible matrices (which you mentioned in the question) and in the case of zero matrices (of the same shape).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column space of each of the two matrices $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

is a subspace generated by the columns of the matrix.

Since the columns of each matrix are two linearly independent vectors, the column space of each is a two dimensional subspace of $ R^2$ which is $ R^2$.

Thus they have the same column space.

Comment: As far as I understand while comparing several different matrices and their fundamental subspaces I must look only on spaces that they span and not on the content of each column?

Comment: Correct. We look at the subspace not at the individual basis vectors

Comment: The contents of each column are still important. If you want to know if 2 matrices $A$ and $B$ have the same column space it's equivalent of checking the following $Ax=b$ has a solution for every column $b$ of matrix $B$ and $Bx=a$ has a solution for every column $a$ of matrix $A$. Note that the matrix vector multiplication $Ax$ is just a linear combination of the columns of $A$ so it can also be interpreted as: every column of $B$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ and every column of $A$ is a linear combination of the columns of $B$.